# Marketing Cloud SDK iOS - Inbox Messages getting disappear after relogin

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, inbox

I have an issue with Marketing Cloud iOS SDK.I am using inbox message functionality in my app and it is working fine until the user is logged out.

When the user is login again in the same device, the message is not appearing.

My question is what happend to the messages when user is logged in again?
Does anyone have similar problem,please help me.

Comment: Did you ask to have per-user messaging turned on for Inbox Messages?  It's an app/account setting that you must specifically request.  Also, what do you mean be "logged in" or "logged out" because those are NOT SDK concepts: please describe what you're doing to log in/out a customer.

Comment: Log in mean every time user log in to the App, set a unique ContactKey per user to SDK. I am working on both iOS and Android, In android on user switching both user get same inboxMessages but in iOS on  user switching messages got cleared. What is the actual functionality occured on user switching??

Comment: How are you logging the previous customer out and then how are you refreshing the inbox messages?  The SDK does not have a logged in/logged out state.  Also, you still did not answer: have you requested, explicitly with your administrator, that your MID be configured for per-contact inbox messaging rather than per-device messaging?